# In PostgreSQL, will VACUUM reset the dead tuple count (n_dead_tup in pg_stat_all_tables)?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

In PostgreSQL, will VACUUM reset the dead tuple count (n_dead_tup in pg_stat_all_tables)?

The situation I'm seeing is that vacuum is apparently being run manually, once daily, and the n_dead_tup / n_live_tup data shows that there are a large, and increasing number of dead tuples.

PostgreSQL 9.3 here.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: A possible explanation: [What are the consequences of not ending a database transaction?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33815267/939860)

Comment: n_dead_tup / n_live_tup are updated by stats_collector.

Comment: Ok, so presumably the stats_collector should notice when the table was vacuumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it resets the value. But it is from the stats collector, not vacuum.

```
postgres=# create table x (a int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into x values (1),(2),(3),(4);
INSERT 0 4
postgres=# delete from x where a%2 =0;
DELETE 2

postgres=# \x
Expanded display is on.
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_all_tables where relname='x';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+----------
relid               | 588915846
schemaname          | public
relname             | x
seq_scan            | 1
seq_tup_read        | 4
idx_scan            |
idx_tup_fetch       |
n_tup_ins           | 4
n_tup_upd           | 0
n_tup_del           | 2
n_tup_hot_upd       | 0
n_live_tup          | 2
n_dead_tup          | 2
n_mod_since_analyze | 6
last_vacuum         |
last_autovacuum     |
last_analyze        |
last_autoanalyze    |
vacuum_count        | 0
autovacuum_count    | 0
analyze_count       | 0
autoanalyze_count   | 0



postgres=# vacuum x;
VACUUM

postgres=# select * from pg_stat_all_tables where relname='x';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+------------------------------
relid               | 588915846
schemaname          | public
relname             | x
seq_scan            | 1
seq_tup_read        | 4
idx_scan            |
idx_tup_fetch       |
n_tup_ins           | 4
n_tup_upd           | 0
n_tup_del           | 2
n_tup_hot_upd       | 0
n_live_tup          | 2
n_dead_tup          | 0
n_mod_since_analyze | 6
last_vacuum         | 2016-01-12 16:49:32.248731+08
last_autovacuum     |
last_analyze        |
last_autoanalyze    |
vacuum_count        | 1
autovacuum_count    | 0
analyze_count       | 0
autoanalyze_count   | 0
```

Comment: Which Postgres version did you test?